# How to check if a number starts with Special Characters using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

Using following regexp I can get if a string starts with `a` or `b`.

```
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(a|b)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("0I am a string");
        boolean b = m.find();
        System.out.println("....output..."+b);
```

But I need to check if the string starts with some special characters like `*` or `^` etc. In that case the following regexp gives Pattern error.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(*|^)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("0I am a string");
        boolean b = m.find();

        System.out.println("....output..."+b);
```

**How to check if a number starts with `*` or `^` using regular expression**

Comment: try "^[*^]"....., inside pattern.compile

Comment: You need to escape those characters and also it is good to use Patterns in java like this:
**Instantiation**
`private Matcher matcher; 
private final Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile( pattern ); 
matcher = regexPattern.matcher("");`
**In your method..**
`if(matcher.reset(charBuffer).find() ) {//matching pattern.}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to mathematical.coffee for nice response

Finally I found a solution by using `^[*^]` as regexp to test whether a string contains `*` or `^`

**Source Code**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[*^]");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("I am a string");
        boolean b = m.find();

        System.out.println("....output..."+b);
```

Answer (score 3):

Characters like `|*.[](){}?+^$` have special meaning in regex. Use `[\^*]` (within a `[]` only `]` and `-` have special meaning), or escape them like `^(\*|\^)`.

Comment: If i use [^*] then it gives wrong results. It gives reslut as true for string which doesnt start with * or ^ also

Comment: I tried Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^*]");
  Matcher m = p.matcher("5I am a string");
  boolean b = m.find();

  System.out.println("....output..."+b);

Comment: The regex `^[^*]` tests whether a string starts with a `*` or `^`. The string `5I am a string` clearly does not start with a `*` or `^`.

Comment: Furthermore, are you looking for `*` or `^` followed by a number? In that case, do `^[*^][0-9]` (if all you want is to test for existence as opposed to extracting the entire match).

Comment: `[^*]` does *not* match `^` or `*`; it matches any character except `*`.  The caret (`^`) right after the opening bracket of a character class inverts the meaning of the class.  At any other position it matches a literal caret, so `[*^]` *does* match `^` or `*`.

Comment: oops thanks @AlanMoore, rookie mistake! (and I used to do regex for a job too!) fixed it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

`*` and `^` are special characters in regex which need to be escaped, so you will need to use a `\` to escape it.

See [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
"0I am a string".matches("[\\^*].*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `'(\^|\*)[0-9]+'` for the purpose.

Since both `^` and `*` are special characters in regex, you'll need to put `\` before them.

If you wish that the whole string must match with it, put the regex between `^` and `$`.